# how to create a SEARCH button like to database SELECT statement in android

Tags: android

I'm building a dictionary application for android.
I would like to create a SEARCH button that can search through the SQLite database, then display the data to ListView.

1. how can code in order for me to link that SEARCH button to database SELECT statement?
2. how to display SELECT statement result to a ListView?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a query depending on the contents of the search bar, something like:

```
select * from <your_database> where word = "<word typed in the search field>"
```

i.e. you'll have to create a basic String e.g. `select * from <your_database> where word = "` and then concatenate it with the contents of the search bar when Select button is pressed.

additionally you'd want to use word `like "#<word typed in the search field>#"`

and split the word and detect similar words and search them in the database, this is specific to the implementation you are talking about i.e dictionary. I mean for example if I type `cavalier` in the dictionary, the dictionary results also include `cavalier hat`, but these depend on your objectives.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a database tutorial for android.

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) should help you work with the `ListView`

Comment: Hi SpeedBirdNine, how can I get the user input to put at the WHERE clause?

Comment: Well it is a dictionary application, so obviously you would give the user some search field to enter the word he is looking for, get the input from that field, use a plain text field

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with `ListView` you can use my code
Its doing the same thing i.e. getting input from textfield, searching for it in db and print result in `ListView`

```
    EditText userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    SQLiteClass mySQLiteClass = new SQLiteClass(this);
    mySQLiteClass.openToWrite();
    Cursor cursor = mySQLiteClass.returnResultsFromDb(userInput.getText().toString);

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()) {
       result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteClass.BI_Attr2)));
    }

    String[] Values = new String[result.size()];

    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
        Values[i] = result.get(i);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, android.R.id.text1, Values);

    ListView LV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And following in my database class

```
public class SQLiteClass{

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "DATABASE_Proj";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "Basic_Info";
    public static final String BI_Attr1 = "ID"; // Primary Key
    public static final String BI_Attr2 = "Name";
    public static final String BI_Attr3 = "StudentRoll";
    public static final String BI_Attr4 = "FromCourse";
    public static final String BI_Attr5 = "ToCourse";
    public static final String BI_Attr6 = "Time";
    public static final String BI_Attr7 = "Status";
    public static final String BI_Attr8 = "Comments";


    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table "
        + MYDATABASE_TABLE + 
        " (" + BI_Attr1         + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        BI_Attr2 + " text not null, " +
        BI_Attr3 + " text," +
        BI_Attr4 + " text," + 
        BI_Attr5 + " text," +
        BI_Attr6 + " text," +
        BI_Attr7 + " text," +
        BI_Attr8 + " text " +

        "); ";


    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteClass(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLiteClass openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteClass openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor returnResultsFromDb(String S) {
        String[] columns = new String[] { BI_Attr3 };
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
            } catch (Exception E) {
                Log.v("Failed to create DB", "----");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Raheel, thanks. where should I use your code? into onClick method of Activity class? Sorry Im new to android.

Comment: use my updated code
I previously forgot to setAdapter in ListView

Comment: SQLiteClass is my Class having database, you will have your own database class for this purpose
Change my code Instead of SQLiteClass use your own db class name

Comment: Ok I am adding mydb class in my answer
Add remove attributes of table according to your requirement

Comment: This time is "SQLiteAdapter" with red underline which I use in my Activity class. Is that your class also?

Comment: U need to just rename it with SQLiteClass